# Defining Repository for MVC best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static, singleton, repository

I want to have a single repository for all my classes/entities. All the controllers from an MVC app should be able to use this repository without creating new instances. The repository must have an extracted interface, for testing or other purposes - therefore the repository class will not be static, since static classes cannot implement interfaces. Yet, it will have a static property, which will be available without instantiating the Repository class. The constructor might be redundant or replaced by a method. Please let me know if it's a good implementation or a bad practice. Or let me know if could be improved somehow:

```
 public class Repository : IRepository
 {
    private MyDBContext context;

    private static Repository _instance;
    public static Repository Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Repository(new MyDBContext());
            }
            return _instance;
        }            
    }

    public Repository(MyDBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;     
        if(_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new Repository(context);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: after using more dbContext, I've found that sharing an instance of dbContext is not good, due to concurrency issues or disposal side effects. Therefore, what I intended shouldn't be done anyway, beware!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing technically wrong with what you propose. There are some improvements though.
The static constructor is guaranteed to run once and only once before the first call to a static member. You therefore remove the race condition you had in your code when 2 method call your Instance property. The null coalescing operator in the constructor means you get a default implementation, but you could override it for testing.

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private MyDBContext context;

    public static IRepository Instance
    {
        get;
        private set;            
    }

    static Repository()
    {
        Instance = new Repository(null);
    }

    public Repository(MyDBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context ?? new MyDBContext();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, your suggested solution seems clearer and better. Thank you!